# How to clear one opened activity and create it again from another activity/Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android

In my one of my activity shows ads when it called by some Broadcast receiver. Suppose my ads's activity is opened. I want to call it again from Broadcast Receiver but I want to finish previous ads' activity before re create it again. How to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Change its launch mode to [singleTop or singleInstance](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in the AndroidManifest.

I would go for singleTop and override `onNewIntent()` to handle intent changes. This way, you don't have to close your activity.

Comment: Thanks.I want to finish previous instance of activity if opened.using singleInstance or SingleTop its not working. Actually I am getting diff ads at every new call of that activity. Any way how to call recreate method, its not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Call the intent to the activity from your broadcast receiver and set the following flag to the intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

or

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: This will finish some other opened activities and do not want to do that.

Comment: Do you want to change the ad through broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

use [recreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) method in Activity

Comment: Thanks.How to call recreate method, its not getting called.

Comment: when you receive broadcast action in your Activity, call recreate method